# Declare not found and cannot open =: No such file

Tags: bash, shell-script

Hello i'm using Ubuntu 19.10 and bash version is 5.0.3(1)-release. I'm trying to writte script. I checked my bash with **which bash** command and return was **/usr/bin/bash** so u put it on first line of script.

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
declare -i n = 1
while [ $n <= 99 ]
do 
  echo $n 
  n = $((n+2))
done
```

When i try run it i get two errors:
 *test.sh: 2: declare: not found* and *test.sh: 3: cannot open =: No such file*

Comment: [www.shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net)

Comment: It looks like you're running this script with `dash`  instead of `bash`, is that right? Are you running it with `sh test.sh`?

Comment: i was using sh script_name.sh now is working. Thx steeldriver. :) When i run it with ./script_name.sh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are four things in your script that you should consider changing.  Two of them are syntax related:

1. Assignments can not have spaces around `=`. You have this error in two places.
2. To do an arithmetic less than or equal test, use `-lt`, not `<=`.  The `<=` is an input redirection from a file called `=`.  This is where your "`no such file`" error comes from.

The other two are:

1. Always double quote expansion.  Use `echo "$n"` or `printf '%s\n' "$n"` instead of `echo $n`. Use `[ "$n" -lt 99 ]` instead of `[ $n -lt 99 ]`.  In the general case, the shell would otherwise split the variable's value into words and apply filename globbing rules to each of those words.
2. You don't need `declare -i` here.  Declaring a variable as integer in `bash` is very rarely needed.

Additionally, since you get a "`declare not found`" error, you are likely not running the script with `bash`. Do consider making your script executable and also *don't* specify an explicit interpreter on the command line when you run your script (this would make the `#!` line take effect).

See also:

- [When is double-quoting necessary?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68694)
- The https://www.shellcheck.net/ web site is useful for checking shell script syntax.